in PERN App(Todo List) , EditTodo.js PUT request showing 404 (Not Found)
I have built PERN todo app. It is my first time to build an app that has a backend connecting to a frontend with database.
I have an issue with put request. It does work in Postman.
But on browser, it does not work. I get status code error of 404.
I spent almost a week researching to figure this out, but i could not make it work yet. It would be nice if someone could help me out. I would very appreciate if someone can explain what is going on and give me the solution to it.
Image of an error
import React,{Fragment, useState} from "react";

const EditTodo = ({todo}) => {
    
    const [description, setDescription] = useState(todo.description);

    //edit description function
    const updateDescription = async e =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
           const body = { description };
           const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/todos/${todo.todo_id}`,{
            method: "PUT",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
           });

        //    window.location = "/";
        console.log(response);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        }
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-warning" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target={`#id${todo.todo_id}`}>
  Edit
</button>

<div className="modal" id={`id${todo.todo_id}`}>
  <div className="modal-dialog">
    <div className="modal-content">

      <div className="modal-header">
        <h4 className="modal-title">Edit Todo</h4>
        <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
      </div>

      <div className="modal-body">
        <input type="text" className="form-control" value={description} onChange={e  => setDescription(e.target.value)}/>
      </div>

      <div className="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-warning" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onClick={e => updateDescription(e)}>Edit</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default EditTodo;

it should edit when i hi edit button

Share your server-side code that handles the request? You need to use CORS
